# st_difference when x and y have multiple rows

Tags: sf

I'm attempting to remove any part of any polygon in dataset x (1000 rows) that overlaps with any polygon in dataset y (1000 rows).

I'm hoping for a dataset that has the same number of rows as x (or maybe a few less if some rows are left with no geometry because they completely overlap with y).

The only issue is that when I use st_difference, the resulting dataset is 1000*1000 rows, and the process is very slow.

Might be relevant:

- Some rows in y overlap each other
- Many rows in x overlap the same row in y.

Comment: You need to union Y together to make a single multi geometry

Comment: For each row in X, you should only process rows in Y which overlap Xn. This must be a constraint on the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that could help speed up the process created is first creating a spatial index on the geometry column for both datasets X & Y. Secondly you should try using ST_Union on the geometry for dataset Y. Instead of running ST_difference on 1000 entities it will then only have to process it for one. In order to not end up with too many rows you should run the ST_difference only where ST_intersects the geometries of Y and X.

So I think you could try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT X.id, ST_Difference(x.geom, Y.union_geom) as geom
FROM dataset_x as X
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ST_Union(y.geom) as union_geom
FROM dataset_y as y) as Y
ON ST_intersects(X.geom, Y.union_geom);
```